# Singular isothermal density distribution

Tags: thermodynamics, gravity, cosmology, lenses, gravitational-lensing

Does anyone know where the [Singular isothermal density distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_isothermal_sphere_profile)

$$
\rho(r)=\frac{\sigma_{V}^{2}}{2\pi\,G\,r^{2}}
$$

or how it was derived. Are there any good references on how this equation was derived?

Comment: The Wikipedia link provides a reference to [this arXiv preprint](http://arxiv.org/abs/astro-ph/0102341v2), have you checked there and its references?

Comment: I have checked and they do not mention this equation.

Comment: [This](http://www.iucaa.in/~dipankar/ph217/isothsph.pdf) seems to have it.